# count file type if mp3 | Google Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am wondering I understand I can use

```
gsutil ls -lR gs://BUCKET/
```

to count all files, however I want to count only mp3 files, if that is possible. Is their anyway to do a where is file type?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this to search at the folder level (here the root level of the bucket)

```
gsutil ls -lR gs://BUCKET/*.mp3
```

Or recursively

```
gsutil ls -lR gs://BUCKET/**/*.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also display **the total number of mp3 files only** in a bucket using the command below

`gsutil ls gs://bucket/*.mp3 | wc -l`